# Managing UIControls in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, xcode, nsmutablearray, uicontrol

I have an NSMutableArray.

I create a UIControl (say UISlider) and add it to this array in a for loop.

```
for (int i=0; i<totalSlider; i++) {

UISlider *tmpSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithRect:CGRect(0,0,200,40)];

[myArray addObject: tmpSlider];

}
```

This works ok.
I am able to refer to it by

```
UISlider *tmpSlider = [myArray objectAtIndex:j];
```

But how to remove and release these objects individually while maintaining
the remaining sliders in that array?

for example, there are 10 sliders in this array.
So I want to remove slider at index 5. How to go about doing this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you have created all the UISliders in a stack, on top of each one.

as your co-ordinates are same `CGRect(0,0,200,40)];`

So you will be seeing only one of them.

Now if you want to remove any one of them simply use

```
[myArray removeObjectAtIndex:5];
```

EDIT:

An extract from [Jed's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668785/does-removeobject-release-the-object-in-an-nsmutablearray-of-objects).

> Like NSArray, instances of NSMutableArray maintain strong references
>   to their contents. If you do not use garbage collection, when you add an object to an array, the object
>   receives a retain message. When an object is removed from a mutable
>   array, it receives a release message. If there are no further
>   references to the object, this means that the object is deallocated.
>   If your program keeps a reference to such an object, the reference
>   will become invalid unless you send the object a retain message before
>   it’s removed from the array.

Comment: Firstly no, my sliders are not stacked bcause I have codes to set their center points appropriately. Anyway, so I don't need to [[myArray objectAtIndex:j] release]; ?

Comment: release? are you using MRC?

Comment: Ok tq. So I dont need to release manually. Good to know thanks.